# collpase doesn't work in mozilla but works in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

Collapse doesn't seem to work in mozilla firefox but works perfectly in chrome.Here is an example

```
 var r1 = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
 var r2 = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
 console.log(r1.collapsed);  // It is false Now
 console.log(r2.collapsed);  // It is false Now
 r1.collapse(true);
```

Now when you set the r1.collpase to true,r2.collapsed is set to true.But when you try set r2.collapse to false,it remains true.

```
 r2.collapse(false);
 console.log(r2.collapsed); //true
```

I think this is a firefox bug.Correct me if i am wrong.Is there any workaround this in firefox?

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox Selection Range
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/collapsed
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/collapse

The collapse parameters just say in which direction you want to collapse the selection. But after that, it's always collapsed.

Comment: collapsed is also a property in firefox

Comment: My mistake, it's a Range object and not a Selection object.